# ¿Cómo personalizar bordes de los post en Tumblr?

Tags: html, css, css3, tumblr

Quisiera saber si me pueden guiar cómo lograr personalizar los bordes de los post de Tumblr. Quisiera lograr un borde ondulado tal como lo muestra en la imagen.

[image: Lo que busco lograr en tumblr con los post]

Ya encontré el borde en HTML y CSS en este [enlace](https://codepen.io/btargac/pen/JGOGoj):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #ffF;
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wave {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, sandybrown, chocolate);
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.wave::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, white 13px);
}

.wave::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, white 12px, transparent 13px);
}

.content {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave">Tengo un borde ondulado</div>

<div class="content">
  Con dos pseudo-elementos especiales (before y after) y el poder de repetir gradientes radiales de CSS, este tipo de rizos que parecen olas se pueden hacer si necesidad de una imagen.
</div>
```

Pero sinceramente tengo conocimientos muy básicos en esto. Sé que tengo que editar el HTML y los estilos del tema, sin embargo no sé qué elemento en el código modificar y qué debo alterar para lograr lo que quiero en la imagen.

¿Cómo podría aplicar un efecto similar al mostrado arriba, pero en los posts de Tumblr?

Comment: ¿Cómo es el código HTML de los posts de Tumblr?

Comment: Hola Alvaro, el código HTML del tema de tumbrl es este: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6j2PXKNZUgNTlzV1VEQkg2N3c/view?usp=sharing

Pero precisamente no se cómo identificar el que pertenece a los post :(

Comment: Sería mejor que colocaras el código generado y no el código fuente. Y debería ser sólo el código relevante y no el de toda la página.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas lo puedes lograr usando la propiedad `border-image`, lo que tendrias que hacer es crearte la imagen del borde, aqui te muestro un ejemplo

```css
#borderimg1 { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
}

#borderimg2 { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

```html
<p id="borderimg1">Usando la propiedad round</p>
<p id="borderimg2">Usando la propiedad stretched</p>

<p>Imagen original</p><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png">
<p><strong>Nota:</strong> Internet Explorer 10,no soporta border-image property.</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Marco, ¡lo intentaré!